# Reference for the size of n in Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

On the net there are websites and documents saying that n > 30 for central limit theorem to wrok. However, they do not give the reference from which they extract this value. Can anyone know a well-known book or paper which explicitly mention this value for n?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution

Comment: Like @Alex I would assume this is not the Central Limit Theorem but instead using the normal distribution instead of the Student $t$-distribution in a time of statistical tables.  For $n=30$ the $97.5\%$ quantile is about $1.96$ for the normal distribution and $2.04$ for the Student $t$-distribution, which is close if you want to round both to $2.0$ though not very close.  Modern computers mean you do not need this approximation

Comment: In actuality, the validity of this rule of thumb depends quite nontrivially on the distribution in question. For a concrete example, you can look at the binomial($n,1/n$) distribution in comparison to the N($1,1-1/n$) distribution; the two differ by an amount that doesn't go to zero as $n \to \infty$. If you have any statistical software, it is worth plotting this out. This particular situation can be sort of explained by considering to the Berry-Esseen theorem, though the bound that appears in that theorem is not tight in this case (the constant is a few times too large).

Comment: Simple case to look at analytically in the above scenario: if $X$ is binomial($n,1/n$) distributed and $Y$ is $N(1,1-1/n)$ distributed then $P(X \leq 0)=(1-1/n)^n \to e^{-1}$ whereas $P(Y \leq 0)=\Phi \left ( \frac{-1}{1-1/n} \right ) \to \Phi(-1)$. $e^{-1}$ is about $0.37$ while $\Phi(-1)$ is about $0.16$.

Comment: Also I apologize, I didn't quite make the point of my example explicit: the point is that the binomial($n,p$) CDF differs quite significantly from the $N(np,np(1-p))$ CDF when $np$ (or $n(1-p)$) is not very large, even if $n$ *is* very large. Thus for example it makes no sense to use the CLT to approximate the distribution of a sum of 100 independent Bernoulli(0.01) variables, even though it already makes decent sense to use the CLT to approximate the distribution of a sum of 30 independent Bernoulli(0.5) variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the excellent *Probability and Statistical Inference* by Nitis Mukhopadhyay.  Specifically, pg. 547.  See the [downloadable pdf](https://www.zuj.edu.jo/download/probability-and-statistical-inference-nitis-mukhopadhyay-pdf/) for the exact reference.